# ConEmu cuts off script execution and requires input when large text is printed

Tags: bash, conemu, cmder

I'm running a bash script in ConEmu that at one point prints json text which has multiple lines. At this point, the printed text is cut off with "--more--", execution is interrupted and ConEmu expects input. I have to press Enter for each consecutive line to appear, and I have to get to the end of the printed text for the script to continue executing.

How do I disable this feature?

[Screenshot: ConEmu interrupts script execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgAwc.png)

The script I am running contains the AWS CLI command `aws lambda update-function-code`, which returns a large json output, as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html#examples). It is this command output that gets cut off.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the bash script you are running, formatted as code.

Comment: Edited. The script is irrelevant (and private) but I added the command that causes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. It is actually caused by the aws command, which is really odd, as it is meant to be used in automation.
Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122188/how-to-turn-off-the-pager-for-aws-cli-return-value

The solution is to set the AWS_PAGER env variable to "" before calling the `aws lambda update-function-code` command.
like so:

```
AWS_PAGER="" aws lambda update-function-code ...
```